# 404 Error when invoke a Rest API in Controller in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have develop a simple SpringBoot application with a rest end point as below,

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api")
public class Example {

   @RequestMapping(value="/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    HttpEntity<String>  home() {
        System.out.println("-----------myService invoke-----------");
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Example.class, args);
    }
}
```

Above works fine and return 200 in when i invoke the rest end point as, 
http://localhost:8080/api/home

But now i have move the rest end point to a different class as below,

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api")
public class MyController {

     @RequestMapping(value="/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        HttpEntity<String>  home() {
            System.out.println("-----------myService invoke-----------");
            return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.OK);
        }   
}
```

And the Example class looks like,

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Example.class, args);
    }
}
```

Now i invoke the end point i get below error,

```
{
  "timestamp": 1446375811463,
  "status": 404,
  "error": "Not Found",
  "message": "No message available",
  "path": "/api/home"
}
```

What am i missing here please?

Comment: Is `MyController` in the same package or sub-package as `Example`?

Answer (score 1):

Please put the classes, MyController and Example in the same package and try again

Answer (score 0):

Or also you can put the package of your controller in the main Application , something like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.controller"})
public class Application
```